# Calculating expected value of $X$ with the density function $f(x)=16xe^{-4x}$

Tags: probability, integration, expected-value

> Suppose, $X$ be a random variable with probability density funciton,
> $$
> f(x) = \begin{cases}
> 16xe^{-4x}, & x \geq 0; \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> ([source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLRxh.png))

I tried to find the expected value of $X$, so I integrated $16x^2 e^{-4x}$ from $0$ to $\infty$.

After finding the indefinite integral with $u$-substitution:$-\frac{1}{2}e^{-4x}(8x^2+4x+1)+C$, I tried to compute the integral solution with the aforementioned boundaries and here is where I am not certain whether I calculated it right.

It might have gone wrong when I plugged in $\infty$ for $x$. I get $0-(-1/2)=1/2$. Is this correct or am I supposed to get something undefined and can one even get undefined expected value/mean?

When you subtract something from infinity, isn't it undefined? Same as multiplying $0$ with infinity?

Comment: You are not subtracting anything from infinity.  You are subtracting from $0$, which is well defined.  If you want to be more sure, make your integral up to some large $N$, which will give a finite result, and take the limit as $N \to \infty$.  That is where the $0$ comes from.

Comment: okay I worded that wrongly, indeed I subtracted from 0.

Comment: Does that resolve your question?  It seemed to be the source of the concern.

Comment: My main concern has been addressed. But I want to also know if it's possible to get undefined expected value/variance?  And does that even make sense?

Comment: Yes, you can get the expected value or variance to be undefined if the pdf is badly behaved.  The integral then does not converge when you let the upper limit go to infinity.  It is more common with the variance because then you multiply the pdf by $x^2$, which is more likely to diverge, but it can happen with the expected value as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your solution is fine, indeed we have

$$\int_0^\infty 16x^2e^{-4x}dx=\left[-\frac12e^{-4x}(8x^2+4x+1)\right]_0^\infty=0-\left(-\frac12\right)=\frac12$$

More in detail what we are solving is the following limit

$$\lim_{a\to \infty} \int_0^a 16x^2e^{-4x}dx=\lim_{a\to \infty}\left[-\frac12e^{-4x}(8x^2+4x+1)\right]_0^a=0-\left(-\frac12\right)=\frac12$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice `trick' to solve it without integrals. The idea is that the density function looks like $x$ to some power times the density of a known random variable, so their moments are linked.

Let $Y$ be an exponential random variable with a coefficient $4$. So the pdf is $4e^{-4x}$.
Now,
$$E(X)=\int_0^\infty 16x^2 e^{-4x} dx =4 \int_0^\infty 4x^2 e^{-4x} = 4E(Y^2)$$
$Y$ is a known random variable so we know that $E(Y)=0.25$ and $V(Y)=0.25^2$. Substitute it to the equation for variance to obtain $E(Y^2)=V(Y)+E^2(Y)=\tfrac{1}{8}$ and $E(X)=\tfrac{1}{2}$.